# how to print a 2D array from class if the we print the object the of the this class in main class

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a class `Employee` which has a method that returns a 2D array with some employee information.
I have another class `TestEmployee` in the same package where I create an object test of the class `Employee` and then print this object.

```
Employee test = new Employee();
System.out.println(test);
```

Now this test object should print the array I created in `Employee`. I am not able to write the code to do that. Can someone please help me with this question?

Thanks

Comment: make a toString() method for employee, and do `System.out.println(test.toString());`

Comment: Davis, Is there a way that toString() does not have to be called? I mean I don't have to write test.toString() and only test.

Comment: you could make/use a method to retrieve the 2D array, and then use `Arrays.toString()` inside of a for loop. Here's a link to a question that has a good example of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397535/print-two-dimensional-array-of-strings-as-string

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328661/explicit-vs-implicit-call-of-tostring, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051481/how-an-object-will-call-tostring-method-implicitly (implicit calling of `toString()`), and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java (how to use `toString()`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know why someone would downvote this question.

Employee is an Object type, and you can't print Objects and expect good output because it prints out its hash code (thanks Obicere).

Well, unless you override the toString() method. If you do, and you do it well, you can do:

```
System.out.println(test.toString());
```

I'm assuming you want to print out the information contained in the 2D array. If that's so, then you'd want to parse all that information into a single String and have your toString() method return that.

Cheers,
Justin

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, my TestEmployee class has the main method. Suppose I write a toString() method. Is there any way, I don't have to do the test.toString() to call. I mean can it be called directly?

Comment: Erm, you can try doing it directly once you've overridden toString(). I'm not sure if it'd work though since I've never really tried myself, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: `or some hex number I don't know.` Its actually the `hashCode()` value. Also, `System.out.println(test);` will call `test.toString()` after performing a null-check. There is no notable difference between your code and the answer's code.

Comment: Oh, okay. TIL. Either way, she'd still have to override the toString() method to return whatever is in those 2D arrays of hers. Thanks for the new knowledge, lol.

Comment: @theguywhodreams : I was able to print out directly after overriding the toString() method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is extremely late but you use deepToString() to print out a multidimensional array.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :)